Group property of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms under composition
Consider the following proposition from the book: Polterovich, Leonid. The geometry of the group of symplectic diffeomorphism. Birkhäuser, 2012.
Proposition 1.4.D. (Hamiltonian of the product) Consider two Hamiltonian paths $\{f_t\}$ and $\{g_t\}$. Let $F$ and $G$ be their normalized Hamiltonian functions. Then the product path $h_t = f_tg_t$ is a Hamiltonian path generated by the normalized Hamiltonian function
$$
H(x, t) = F(x, t) + G(f_t^{-1} x, t).
$$
The way I interpret this is: if $f_t$ and $g_t$ are the time-$t$ solutions to the Hamiltonian systems $\dot{x}=J\nabla F$ and $\dot{x}=J\nabla G$, where $J$ is the canonical symplectic matrix, then their composition $f_t\circ g_t$ is the solution to the $\dot{x}=J\nabla H$. Meaning that $f_t\circ g_t$ should have $H$ as a preserved quantity. I.e., $$H\circ(f_t\circ g_t) = H.$$
However, I don't see how this is the case as
$$H\circ(f_t\circ g_t) = (F + G\circ f_t^{-1})\circ f_t\circ g_t = F\circ g_t+G\ne F+G\circ f_t^{-1},$$
where we have used $F\circ f_t=F$ and $G\circ g_t=G$. Where have I gone wrong here?
Furthermore, I thought that the Hamiltonian of the composition of Hamiltonian flows is again a Hamiltonian flow with (modified) Hamiltonian given by the BCH formula, that is $f_t\circ g_t$ is the solution of an ODE $\dot{x} = J\nabla H$ with
$$H = F + G + t \{F, G\} + ...$$
where $\{F, G\}$ is the Poisson bracket. This is (formally) an infinite series for sufficiently small $t$. The above BCH series doesn't look at all like it will give $F + G\circ f_t^{-1}$. How are these two facts compatable?

I suspect my confusion arises from a misunderstanding between Hamiltonian "paths" and "flows". Tho I am not sure where to go from there.

Regarding the first part of the question: The flow $\Psi_t$ of a time-dependent Hamiltonian $H_t$ does not necessarily satisfy the equation $H_t \circ \Psi_t = H_0$.  A simple counter example would be to take $H_t = t$; the flow is constant, but the value of the Hamiltonian increases. You can also construct normalized examples by taking $H_t=t$ in some neighborhood, and compensating in some other neighborhood. See also this question that was not yet answered.
Regarding the second part of the question: It seems to me that for time-independent Hamiltonians $F$ and $G$, the definition in Polterovich's book and the definition given by the BCH formula agree. For instance, you can verify that the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} H$ is indeed the Poisson bracket of $X_F$ and $X_G$.
